# Creating a square pyramid with subdivided triangles

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to create a square pyramid with subdivided triangles in blender.
So far I've tried to create using cone and plane extruded. I'm able to create a square pyramid with same base and triangle length (by extruding a plane and merging). But I'm unable to subdivide each triangle face it into 8 equal triangles (as in the picture). Could someone assist me on this?

[image: Side view]
[image: 3d view]

Comment: Hello, weird because I've just tried and a simple Subdivide seems to work fine: https://zupimages.net/up/21/44/wpye.jpg

Comment: @moonboots could you please stare your steps? I'm new to blender

Comment: create your pyramid (for example create a cone and in the Operator box, on the bottom left of the 3D view, choose Vertices > 4), switch to Edit mode, select all, right click > Subdivide, in the Operator box choose Number of Cuts > 2

Comment: one minute late :( I even prepared a GIF for the answer :(

Comment: @Ribbit12 you can still answer, especially if you know how to make an equilateral 5 face pyramid

Comment: but my answer is so similar to your answer

Comment: @Ribbit12 I don't know how to make an equilateral pyramid though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How to model an equilateral triangular pyramid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/how-to-model-an-equilateral-triangular-pyramid/12227) **(click on this link if you want to make a subdivided equilateral pyramid)**

Please follow these GIFs to achieve this result
**(The result is not an equilateral pyramid)**

[image]

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2 (optional)**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131236/discussion-on-answer-by-ribbit12-creating-a-square-pyramid-with-subdivided-trian).