# How to create correct tetrahedron (platonic shape) in blender 2.8?

Tags: add-on

Following instruction on this [post on stack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10725/how-do-i-create-an-equilateral-tetrahedron), I managed to turn on add-on, but I can't find it in add function.
So, where should I look after it or how to even create tetrahedron on blender 2.8 (if its version related)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing has changed.

The Add extra objects addon is still there:

[image]

Then use add>mesh>math function>regular solid

[image]

Then use Source: Tetrahedron.

[image]