# Multiple rotations do not add up

Tags: transforms

I am trying to place 4 object on a sphere so that they are equidistant. I can do this by placing them at the 4 corners of a tetrahedron, and a tetrahedron is just 4 corners of a cube. (The cube is just a construction object that will go away.)

I put my object at 0,0,0, then rotate it 45 degrees on two axes. (I then translate it to the corner of the cube.)

**See screenshot part 1**

I know this worked because when I turn the look down the corner of the cube, I can see my object is perfectly aligned.

**See screenshot part 2**

But when I add the sphere in, *the object is not perpendicular to the sphere's surface.*

**See screenshot part 3**

What have I done wrong? I'm pretty sure I'm doing the multiple axis rotation correct. I set the **Transformation Orientation** to Local so the rotations should be relative to the object, not Global.

(I can fix it manually by rotating X to **about** 54 degrees rather than 45, but that's pretty sloppy.)

What am I doing wrong? Or better yet, is there an easier way of placing 4 objects at equidistant angles from each other?

[image: 3 screenshots of an object on a sphere at four corners of a cube]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10725/how-do-i-create-an-equilateral-tetrahedron

Comment: Yes, the tetrahedron is easy. The four corners of a cube form a tetrahedron. The issue I'm having is getting objects to rotate correctly so they are stuck on the apeces of the tetrahedron.

Comment: Sorry, thinking out loud, and then I got called away.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Four little monkeys, sitting on a tetrahedron]

My first thought was that the vectors from the origin of a regular unit tetrahedron are normal to the plane tangent to the sphere where the vector intercepts, and we must be able to recover the rotation from that.

We see that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron?section=2#Coordinates_for_a_regular_tetrahedron) gives the rather ugly values of $( 0, 0, 1 )$, $(\sqrt{\frac{8}{9}},         0, -1/3 )$, $( -\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}, -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, -\frac{1}{3} )$, and $( -\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, -\frac{1}{3} )$ for these vertices, so I wrote some Python to draw it.

```
D = bpy.data
from math import sqrt, radians
from mathutils import Vector

radius = 1

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add(source='4', size=radius)

tetrahedron = C.active_object


empties = []

theta = radians(120)
vectors = [ Vector( (   0, 0, 0, 1 ) ),
            Vector( ( theta, sqrt(8/9),         0, -1/3 ) ),
            Vector( ( theta,-sqrt(2/9), -sqrt(2/3), -1/3 ) ),
            Vector( ( theta,-sqrt(2/9),  sqrt(2/3), -1/3 ) ),]
hack=[ 0, 2, 3, 1]


for n in range(4):
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='SINGLE_ARROW', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
    empties.append(C.active_object)

    empties[n].rotation_mode= 'AXIS_ANGLE'
    empties[n].rotation_axis_angle = vectors[n]
    empties[n].location = radius * Vector(vectors[hack[n]][1:4])


for n in range(4):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=0.5, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', 
        location=radius * Vector(vectors[hack[n]][1:4]) )
    monkey = C.active_object
    monkey.rotation_mode= 'AXIS_ANGLE'
    monkey.rotation_axis_angle = vectors[n]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up doing it manually by orienting the cube so I am looking exactly down a vertex of the cube in ortho mode. I can simply fiddle with the rotation of the smaller object until it's exactly aligned. Looks like 45deg and 35.4deg. I only have to do this once, then I can duplicate x3 it and simply change the +/- signs as-needed. Not my favorite way of doing it, but it worked.